# jedis not releasing connections / jedis leaking connections / jedis connection pool exhausted over time

Tags: redis, jedis, redislabs

I've a tomcat server and using jedis client to connect to it.

The jedis version I am using is "3.0.0-m1" and tomcat 8.0.15

After connecting and after a few hours I see the below exceptions. Any help on this?

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host test-1234.catalog.com:1234
            Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: test-1234.catalog.com:1234
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be to check the max number of clients in your Redis server, maybe the Jedis pool has reached that max number and the server is not accepting any new connections.

Comment: There is no issue with the number of connections on redis or max clients ot can accept.